# How to truncate Directory lines in "wc -l" command?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal, fedora

I am trying to get total number of lines in all of the files in the current working directory

in order to do this i tried  this following command

```
wc -l * | tail -1
```

But this command also returns me the directories..

my output is like

```
wc: Folder1: Is a directory
wc: Folder2: Is a directory
wc: Folder3: Is a directory
1714 total
```

I want only the return number(1714 in this case) in the output.
And then i will assign it into variable to use it later.

How can i truncate the directory lines?

Later on i may want to use this command with relative path...
I don't know how to call wc -l command with relative directory parameter either?

Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
wc -l * 2>/dev/null
```

Better command would be using `find` to get only files:

OR else:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -I % cat % | wc -l
```

OR else:

```
wc -l --files0-from=<(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0) | awk 'END{print $1}'
```

Comment: That's work fine for me thanks.. How can i add relative path to it?

Comment: They're already relative paths. `wc -l ./*` will show them with a partially qualified path, and `wc -l "$PWD"/*` will show them with absolute path.

Comment: @Webster: I have provided a better `find` command for this. In `find` command you can put any path instead of `.` to get count from that directory.

Comment: I change my command to find command thanks for it and how can i truncate the total word from output? i tried cut but couldnt handle it.Because of my lack of knowledge about unix

Comment: well.. That's nice. Thanks for your help really.But if you explain what the commands used for what and explainings for beginners like me? That would be perfect :) thanks again

Comment: `find` command gets all files in current directory and prints with null byte separator. `xargs` runs `cat` on each of the file and `wc -l` just prints total lines. Check `man xargs` for more details on `xargs` command.

Answer (score 1):

```
find -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec cat {} ";" | wc -l
```

Comment: `+` instead of `;` will make it more efficient. I'm not sure `-mindepth` is useful.

Comment: Didn't know of `+`, that makes `xargs` less useful to me. Here's a new version: `find -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec wc -l {} "+" | awk 'END{print $1}'`